# Tikz draw line over node without clipping at node shape border

Tags: tikz

In section 17.11 of the TikZ manual https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.11, it is said that sometimes Tikz is trying to be clever and "the -- path operation will not draw a line from the center of x, but from the border of x". I want to suppress this behaviour and have an edge cross a node shape without premature arrow tips. What would be the syntax?

I tried to run an edge from the center of a node to the center of another node, using `draw (firstnode.center) -- (secondnode.center)`.

Comment: Can you add a small test document which reproduces your problem? Your `\draw (firstnode.center) -- (secondnode.center);` seems to work as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knhkq.png